# How to make my Discord bot send a message to the chat

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I want to make a few simple chat commands. I have searched on the web a little but I haven't really found anything understandable

```
import discord



client = discord.Client()

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("THE SHEEP BOT IS HERE!")
    await client.change_presence(activity=discord.Game("a bot"))

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return

    if message.content == "Hey":
        await client.send_message(message.channel, "Hey.")

client.run("MYTOKEN")
```

At the moment the bot just has its status as "A bot" which is fine, I made it do that, just when I as a user in discord type Hey, the bot does nothing.

I also get this error when I run the program

```
    await client.send_message(message.channel, "Hey.")
AttributeError: 'Client' object has no attribute 'send_message'
```

Comment: It *does* do something, it tries to send a message, but it can't because that method doesn't exist [on `Client`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#client).

Comment: `client.send_message` was deprecated after migration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `send_message`, try `message.channel.send`.

for example:

```
await message.channel.send("Hey.")
```

By the way, the reason why `send_message` doesn't work is because it uses the async version of discord.py, which was deprecated. [Here's the github issue.](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/issues/2138)